# Https connection for web service

Tags: java

i am trying to connect with https site but i am getting response code=500 when i send my request XML don't why i am getting this error when i am trying to get response from web service.below is my sample code.Please help me out from this problem.

```
public static HttpsURLConnection gethttpsConnection(String wsdl,
            String soapAction, StringBuffer buf) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(wsdl);
            HttpsURLConnection connjava = (HttpsURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connjava.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connjava.setRequestProperty("Content-length",
                    "" + Integer.toString(buf.toString().getBytes().length));
            connjava.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            connjava.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            connjava.addRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
            connjava.setDoOutput(true);
            connjava.setDoInput(true);
            connjava.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            java.io.DataOutputStream printout = new java.io.DataOutputStream(
                    connjava.getOutputStream());
            printout.writeBytes(buf.toString());

            if (connjava != null) {

                Logs.logger.info("Response Code : "
                        + connjava.getResponseCode());
                X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) connjava
                        .getServerCertificates();
                for (X509Certificate cert : certs) {

                    Logs.logger.info("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
                    Logs.logger.info("Cert Public Key Algorithm : "
                            + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
                    Logs.logger.info("Cert Public Key Format : "
                            + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
                }



                printout.flush();
                printout.close();
 return connjava;
            }
```

Comment: Please include the stacktrace from the server log.

Comment: Server Error 500 is Internal Server error. Read my answer, it might help you with the same.

Comment: There is one more suggestion, this error is not because of your code. (I think so.) And if you want to secure the connection using SSL, then include the SSL file. No need to write this code, you implement SSL and be free with this code. And 500 error is irrespective of your code. But atlast, I am not sure about it. Please check other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience of web-development with `Java`, but yes, I have worked over `Php`, there I had the same problem of `server Error - 500`. It was because of the session value mismatch. I had two websites sharing the same `session` variable names. This lead to mismatch in active `sessions`, And I got this error. Check with that, I guess you might be making the same mistake.